# How can I call "trivial" quadrics, like empty set, single point, straight line, plane, two lines, two planes...?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, analytic-geometry, quadrics

My temptation is to call it degenerate quadrics. But, in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space), the list of degenerate quadrics also includes cylinders and conic quadrics. On the other hand, in [these notes](https://math.ucr.edu/%7Eres/math10A/quadrics.pdf), the author uses the term degenerate as I would use: only for quadrics that are finite unions of "euclidean primitive objects" (points, straight lines and planes). Is this terminology acceptable?

Comment: Since there are reputable places that use different conventions you can choose the one you like. Just make sure you explain your choice to your readers.

Comment: I wonder how someone that follows wikipedia nomenclature would call that kind of quadrics (empty set, single point, line(s), plane(s)).

Comment: When you write a paper, you get to play the role of the Humpty Dumpty from Alice in Wonderland: "'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.'"  **You** get to define your terms, and any terms you choose are, broadly speaking, "acceptable."  You will run into some trouble if you try to use a commonly used term in a way that is different from the common usage, but when a common or universal usage is lacking (as seems to be the case here), you have free rein.